# Public:// doesn't work

Tags: files

I am trying to code as follows:

> $uri='public://admin/myfile.txt';

but `if (file_exists($uri))` fails

the complete path

> $uri='/var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/sites/default/files/admin/myfile.txt';

works and passes `(file_exists($uri))`

`drupal_realpath('public://')` returns `/var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/sites/default/files`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not try this $uri = drupal_realpath('public://').'admin/myfile.txt';

Comment: Thanks, I tried that earlier myself but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Karin Dumb questions: Your public file system is correctly set and you're using PHP 5+? Did you run the checks mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634797/php-file-exists-returning-false-on-some-files ?

Answer (score 2):

The path 'public://admin/myfile.txt' is not a real path (because of the 'public://'-part, which is a drupal-custom), it's a stream-wrapper-path (see link at end of answer).

> file_exists() can only process real-paths and registered stream-wrapper-paths

**This means for you: Either your Drupal-installation didn't register it's custom stream-wrapper or your server-isp deactivated the stream-wrappers on your server/account.**

You should check your php-config for Filesystem and Streams Configuration Options:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

More info on php's stream-wrappers:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

BTW: Registering of custom stream-wrappers is supported by PHP 4.3.2+